# Is it possible to use a vector image on a website?

Tags: image, vector

Is it possible to use a vector image on a website? Perhaps using JavaScript, jQuery or something?

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me as if you need to learn about 'SVG'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is.

Two possible routes are SVG or canvas - have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568136/svg-vs-canvas-where-is-the-web-world-going-towards

There is a world of browser-compat and tooling (e.g. image generation) issues to consider.